How do I report a judge for Bias and misusing his powers in court
How do I report a county circuit Judge for Bias and misusing his powers in court?

Where? Different states and countries have different rules?

Doesn't the lawyer who represented you know?

united-states
Most states have a "judicial review board" or a "judicial review council" empowered to investigate misconduct by judges.  Here's the website of the Connecticut Judicial Review Council, for example.  Lambda Legal has assembled a list of links to judicial review boards for all 50 states as well as the federal judiciary.
The CT Judicial Review Council note that there are some limitations on what they can do:


The council cannot act upon complaints that are made to express dissatisfaction with a decision or ruling.
The council cannot affect the progress or the outcome of a case.
The council cannot disqualify an individual from presiding over a case.
The council cannot act upon complaints alleging improper conduct that occurred outside the statute of limitation as provided by law.


Most other judicial review boards will likely have similar limitations.

Point 3 is strange. What would they do if you think that a judge is biased or bribed (and have proof for it), if not remove him?

@PMF:  IANAL but I think that in some circumstances a history of decisions that favor one side can be grounds for appeal to a higher court, which has the power to reassign a case to a different judge.  (Some folks have speculated about this possibility in one of the Trump cases, for example.)   It's just that the judicial review council doesn't have the power to do this.  Judicial review councils can also recommend that judges be censured, suspended, or in extreme cases removed from office entirely.

@PMF Nobody can force a judge to recuse themselves, but a judge not recusing themselves when proper is a reason for a successful appeal in the next higher court and to throw the case back to a different judge, redoing anything after the moment the recusal happened. Yes, that can involve throwing out a jury verdict. That however is not part of the judicial review board.

Reading the list, suddenly the question comes into my mind, exactly what can this council do. Maybe they could ask to the judge, please next time be more lenient?
